# Installing wordcloud package for python error

Tags: python, package, pip, installation, word-cloud

```
pip install wordcloud
```

This gives me the error "Can't find vcvarsall.bat".

I also tried to install the whl version but everyone I tried gave me the error "not a supported whl on this platform".

Let me know if I need to explain something better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Then pip should work fine!